# WPF custom control - reach element inside, rotate only part of custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls, rotatetransform

I have a problem with custom control.
I have a custom controls, where i have 5-8 Paths, what user can "select". Up of those Paths i want to have label (inside custom control), where i can change the content inside (from Window, where i use that custom control). 
My XAML of the Custom control looks like:

```
<FirstMolarTooth ..........>
<DockPanel>
    <Label Name="lbl_tooth" DockPanel.Dock="Top" FontSize="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Path ......./>
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
</FirstMolarTooth>
```

How can i reach that label inside from window where i use that custom control??
something like:

```
<local:FirstMolarTooth x:Name="Tooth_15" ........>
<lbl_tooth Content="15" />
</local:FirstMolarTooth>
```

or

```
<local:FirstMolarTooth .... Content="15">
</local:FirstMolarTooth>
```

---

Second problem is that i rotate the custom control in window where i use it with:

```
<local:FirstMolarTooth ....>
    <local:FirstMolarTooth.LayoutTransform>
        <RotateTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" Angle="180"/>
    </local:FirstMolarTooth.LayoutTransform>
</local:FirstMolarTooth>
```

My problem is that when i do that (logically), this rotate whole control (with a label). I want to rotate just the Paths and not with the label. I thought that i can do something like custom property for that label "isRotated" and when its setted on true, i should "reset" the rotate (set angle 0) with triggers. But i am not able to do that. (should i reach that custom property from XAML? or only in code? that was maybe the problem i try to reach it from XAML).

I know i can delete the label from custom control and have in there just the Paths and after that rotate just the Paths and the label have in Window. But user can select "whole" custom control (select tooth) and he can select "segment" of tooth (Paths). Therefore i would like to have it everything inside that custom control.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first problem, just bind lbl_tooth against FirstMolarTooth Content property. If that doesn't work, create new dependency property inside FirstMolarTooth(of string) and bind against it. Then you can change that property later outside of custo control.

```
   <FirstMolarTooth x:Name="MOLAR" ..........>
    <DockPanel>
        <Label Name="lbl_tooth" DockPanel.Dock="Top" FontSize="10"                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
           Content="{Binding Content, ElementName=MOLAR}" />
        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Path ......./>
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
```

For the second problem, just make new dependency property of type DOUBULE that you can set outside. For creating dependency properties, you can either google or search this forum. Millions of answers.

```
   <FirstMolarTooth x:Name="MOLAR" ..........>
    <DockPanel>
        <Label Name="lbl_tooth" DockPanel.Dock="Top"   FontSize="10"                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
            Content="{Binding Content, ElementName=MOLAR}" />
        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Path .......>
              <Path.LayoutTransform>
                  <RotateTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" 
                     Angle="{Binding YourNewAngleProperty, ElementName=MOLAR}"/>
              </Path.LayoutTransform>
            </Path>
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
```

Comment: yeah, my problem was that YourNewAngleProperty was unknown in the XAML code. The first one problem is solved (that was the main problem). Marked as answer. thx